# Netezza: Need help in understanding lfinstring option in nzload execution

Tags: netezza

I am using Netezza db and I need help in understanding lfinstring option in nzload command.

Can someone please explain me how above option work with example during nzload execution.

Here is example:
cat test.sql_old

```
"so this is a <LF>

test not as last char of the string"

"and this is a <LF> as last char of the string

"
```

nzload command

```
nzload -db TEST -t tab1  -nullValue '..' -delim '0x1e' -ctrlChars -timeDelim '.' -dateTimeDelim '-'  -df /test/test.sql_old -lfinstring
```

Current Output:

```
nzsql TEST -c "select * from TAB1"  
                                                 COL1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"so this is a <LF>

"and this is a <LF> as last char of the string

test not as last char of the string"

"

(4 rows)
```

Expected Output:

2 rows only

First row

```
so this is a test not as last char of the string
```

Second row

```
and this is a as last char of the string
```

Can we get above output using -lfinstring option or any other option or its not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this example says most there is to know:

> The following command specifies that an embedded newline value that is
>   also the record delimiter is treated as real data:

```
nzload -u admin -pw password -host nzhost -db emp -t name -df /tmp -lfinString
```

[I found it on this IBM online manual page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_the_nzload_command.html)

I hope this helps, otherwise please specify :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I have checked above content in IBM manual page.
I need above nzload command with any example which will give working flow of -lfinstring option.

Comment: Please add some background info.

Comment: Do you have a specific file that you need to load? What error message are you receiving? What software version ? What is the ddl of the target table????

Comment: Added more details in original question.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use lfinstring

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ cat test.txt
so this is a test
not as last char of the string|row1
and this is a as last char of the string
|row2
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzsql -d testdb -c "\d lf_test"
                       Table "LF_TEST"
 Attribute |         Type          | Modifier | Default Value 
-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------
 COL1      | CHARACTER VARYING(50) |          | 
 COL2      | CHARACTER VARYING(10) |          | 
Distributed on random: (round-robin)

[nz@netezza ~]$ nzload -db testdb -df test.txt -t lf_test -lfinstring  -delim '|'
Load session of table 'LF_TEST' completed successfully
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzsql -d testdb -c "select * from lf_test order by col2"
                       COL1                       | COL2 
--------------------------------------------------+------
 so this is a test
not as last char of the string | row1
 and this is a as last char of the string
        | row2
(2 rows)
```

Note that the linefeed is still in the data, so it renders to the screen looking like four rows, but you can see that it is actually 2 rows.

Now, let's reference the actual documentation for the lfinstring option, which can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/r_load_iflnstring.htmlhttp://), noting the bolded parts.

> LFINSTRING OPTION
>
> Specifies whether an embedded newline value that is also the record delimiter is treated as real data.
>   Acceptable values are true or false. The default value is false. **Do not put quotation marks around the value.**
>
> By default, the newline value is the record delimiter. You can change the record delimiter to another value by using the -recDelim option.
>   If the value of the LFinString option is true and the record delimiter is the newline value, the following behavior applies, regardless of the setting of the FillRecord option:
>
> - If the newline value **is not in the last record of the field**, the newline value is treated as real data.
> - If the newline value **is in the last record of the field**, the newline value is treated as the record delimiter unless you escape it.
>
> The LFinString option applies only to data loads. It has no effect on data unloads. This option is not supported for the fixed-length format.

I believe that the last two bolded parts are typographic errors and are inverted.  They should read:

> - If the newline value **is not in the last field of the record**, the newline value is treated as real data.
> - If the newline value **is in the last field of the record**, the newline value is treated as the record delimiter unless you escape it.